# How to send email from android (using the default account)?

Tags: android, email

I would like to leverage the goggle account credentials belonging to the synced user on android to send emails in the background, it is possible to achieve that ?

If not, is it possible to ask the user to send an email (with an intent) AND get the receiver's email ? maybe by calling startActivityForResult ?

Cheers,
Ze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is to send email via intent

```
Intent emailIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"email@address.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

To send email in background use JavaMail API with activation framework.

Comment: Well, If I use your code to issue an Intent to send the email I will not know how many  the receivers were, and the problem for using the JavaMail API is that I need to use the device's owner credentials...

Comment: You cannot query user credentials to use in java mail.

Comment: right, but can I tell the system "sends this emails in the background" ? Or if that isn't possible, after sending emails tell me who he sent it to ?