# How can i send mail from my application

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to send mail from my application . I want to use two fields email address & text. can u help me ?

Comment: -1 for apparent laziness and lack of any indication of prior research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this : [sending email programatically using default user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031844/sending-email-programatically-using-default-user-account)

and this :

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application

for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to do it:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{address});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

And don't forget to add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```