# how to send emails in android

Tags: android, email

I am using following code to send mail from android. It ask chooser when I click button. But I don't want chooser and when I click button it should send mail immediately without redirecting to any other page.

Here is code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String[] recipients = new String[]{"email@example.com", "",};
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending email programatically using default user account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031844/sending-email-programatically-using-default-user-account)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Answer (score 0):

Put this class in your code...this is a email class in which automatically sends your mail via gmail browser without redirecting to any other page as you want...

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body; 

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;
String tag="Mail";

public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

             Log.d("tag",tag);
    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_body,"text/html");

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    this._to = toArr;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..

public void setFrom(String string) {
    this._from = string;

}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    this._subject = string;

}
```

}

and use a function...

```
          private void sendMail() {

    Log.d("----", "sending");
    try {

        Mail m = new Mail("your email id", "password");
        String[] toArr = { "recever id" };


        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("your email id");
        m.setSubject("Information");

        String customHtml="<br/><br/><table border='1'><tr><td><b>"+getResources().getString(R.string.Comment)+"</b></td>" +
                "<td>"+edt_comment.getText().toString()+"</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td><b>"+getResources().getString(R.string.Name)+"</b></td>" +
                "<td>"+edt_name.getText().toString()+"</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td><b>"+getResources().getString(R.string.Email)+"</b></td>" +
                "<td>"+edt_email.getText().toString()+"</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td><b>"+getResources().getString(R.string.Phone)+"</b></td>" +
                "<td>"+edt_phn.getText().toString()+"</td></tr>";

        m.setBody(customHtml);


        if (m.send()) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(P_Ask_Question.this,
                            "Mail has been sent successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    Toast.makeText(
                            P_Ask_Question.this,
                            "Mail is not sent successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: please don't just copy and paste other answers. u can write a comment as a link. or please describe your answer more.

Comment: @Andrain i have used this solution in my code thats y i posted it here as it has solved my problem...

Comment: ohk but u should explain it more

Answer (score -1):

You can try some thing like ..

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

This is simple reference which U did. 
As per your query you need to customize that function by your own.

Refer [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's still giving me to choose. I want it to send mail immediately after clicking button. And how to specify FROM email address in this intent ?

Comment: Have you referred my shared link. If not then please fallow that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do somethink like this

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                  emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"upadhyay.jitesh@gmail.com"});
                 // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{etEmail.getText().toString()});
                  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.feedback_for)+"an interesting place");
                  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etComment.getText().toString()+"\n\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.rating)+rbRating.getRating()+"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.my_contact_number)+etPhoneNumber.getText().toString());
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_send_feedback)));
```

please have a look at

http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-email-with-some-attachment.html

and

http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-using-e-mail-services-for.html